# message text not available when using psloglist

Tags: string, text, message, insertion

I'm using psloglist to analysis the saved event log for my windows 2003 server, however, the critical information i need is not retrieved properly and "message text not available. insertion strings" is appended instead. I've been searching for long while and still unable to find any solution or the root cause, anybody come across the same and could give some help in this? Thanks.

Comment: old thread but did you eventually found a solution? facing the same issue here. when exporting it directly with Event Viewer GUI it is fine whereas with psloglist it's not.

Answer (score 0):

```
psloglist \\localhost -d 7 application -o "Source" | find "MessageText"
```